# Using the grep function in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two matrices of different sizes and need to check if there are any matching numerical values in them. So far I have:

```
url <- readLines("http://www.afip.gob.ar/contacto")
x <- as.matrix(grep("<strong>",url))
x2 <- grep("Centro|prima|Operaciones de Seguro",url)
for(i in 1:length(x2))
{x3 <-(grep(x2[i],x))
}
```

The data is fine since if I enter:

```
x3 <- grep(x2[1],x)
```

It gives me that x3 = 1 as it should.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I realised that if I edited the one line to

```
x3[i] <- grep(x2[i],x)
```

It gives me the matrix I need